# Unable to get response from a servlet if called from a wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, blogs, tomcat

I am having a blog in wordpress which has a link on which javascript is invoked which gives a call to a servlet of mine written in my webapplication.
I am unable to get response from that servlet after clicking on the link.
My blog is running on apace2 server and the webapplication resides on apache tomcat on other server.
Is it a cross domain compatability issue or i need to do some setting in wordpress??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cross domain issue what are the urls for servlet and your wordpress blog?

Comment: wordpress url : http://somedomain1/myblog
webapplication url : http://somedomain1:8090/mywebapp/servletname